# Could the Dor Hamidbar originate Chiddushei Torah?

Tags: torah-study, dor-hamidbar, chiddush

We all imagine that without the burden of physical necessities, Dor Hamidbar (D"H) was busy studying Torah 24/7 (see [@Mbloch's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/106174/15579)).

I wonder, if the source of the Torah (Moses), was close and handy all the time and there was presumably no uncertainty on any subject (besides Moses' own, which he clarified occasionally with G-d), could D"H bring any Torah Chiddushim?

Comment: Isn't that last week's parsha?

Answer (score 2):

It seems from various sections in Rambam's Introduction to the Mishnah that the direct connection was still there as long as Moshe was alive, meaning all forty years. He goes on to say that directly before Moshe's death the people came to him for clarifications on what had been forgotten up until that point. He write further that when he died, and doubts eventually crept in to the laws, they had a system of exegesis using the 13 principles, as well as the rule from Exodus 23:2. To conclude, since there wasn't a chance for doubts to exist as long as Moshe was alive (through ongoing clarification with him), there was no need to make use of the 13 principles to create new clarity in the information. However, that does not mean they could not, there was just no need for it (it seems to me based on Rambam).

> וכן אמרו רבותינו ז"ל בברייתא (בת"כ) וידבר ה' אל משה בהר סיני מה תלמוד לומר בהר סיני והלא כל התורה כולה נאמרה מסיני. אלא לומר לך מה שמטה נאמרה בכלליה ופרטיה ודקדוקיה מסיני אף כל המצות כלליהן ופרטיהן ודקדוקיהן מסיני. והנה לך משל שהקב"ה אמר למשה בסכות תשבו שבעת ימים (ויקרא כג) אחר כן הודיע שהסוכה הזאת חובה על הזכרים לא על הנקבות ושאין החולים חייבין בה ולא הולכי דרך. ושלא יהיה סכוכה אלא בצמח הארץ ולא יסככנה בצמר ולא במשי ולא בכלים אפילו מאשר תצמח הארץ. כגון הכסתות והכרים והבגדים. והודיע שהאכילה והשתיה והשינה בה כלו חובה. ושלא יהיה בחללה פחות משבעה טפחים אורך על שבעה טפחים רוחב. ושלא יהיה גובה הסוכה פחות מעשרה טפחים. וכאשר בא הנביא ע"ה נתנה לו המצוה הזאת ופירושה וכן השש מאות ושלש עשרה מצות הם ופירושם. המצות בכתב והפירוש על פה.
>
> ויהי בארבעים שנה בעשתי עשר חדש בר"ח שבט הקהיל את העם ואמר להם הגיע זמן מותי ואם יש בכם מי ששמע הלכה ושכחה יבא וישאלני ואבאר אותה וכל מי שנסתפקה עליו שאלה יבא ואפרשנה לו כמו שנאמר (דברים א) הואיל משה באר את התורה הזאת לאמר. וכן אמרו חכמים בספרי (פ' דברים) כל ששכח הלכה אחת יבא וישנה וכל שיש לו לפרש יבא ויפרש. ולקחו מפיו ברור ההלכות ולמדו הפרושים כל הזמן ההוא מר"ח שבט עד שבעה באדר. וכשהיה לפני מותו החל לכתוב התורה בספרים וכתב י"ג ספרי תורה גוילים כולם מבי"ת בראשית עד למ"ד לעיני כל ישראל (ב"ב פ"ק דף טו) ונתן ספר לכל שבט ושבט להתנהג בו וללכת בחוקותיו והספר הי"ג נתנו ללוים ואמר להם לקוח את ספר התורה הזה (דברים לא). אח"כ עלה אל ההר בחצי היום השביעי (ספרי פ' האזינו) לחדש אדר (מגילה דף יג:) כפי אשר דקדקה הקבלה.
>
> והיה המקרה ההוא אשר קראו מות בעינינו בשביל שחסרנו ופקדנו אותו וחיים לו לכבוד המעלה שעלה אליה וכן אמרו (סוטה דף יג:) משה רבינו ע"ה לא מת אלא עלה ומשמש במרום והדברים באלו הענינים ארוכים מאד ואין זה מקומם. וכאשר מת ע"ה אחר שהנחיל ליהושע מה שנאצל עליו מן הפירוש והחכים והתבונן בו יהושע ואנשי דורו. וכל מה שקבל ממשה הוא או אחד מן הזקנים אין לדבר עליו ולא נפלה בו מחלוקת. ומי שלא שמע בו פירוש מפי הנביא ע"ה מן הענינים המשתרגים מהם הוציא דינים בסברות במדות השלש עשרה הנתונות על הר סיני שהתורה נדרשת בהם. ובאותם הדינים שהוציאום יש דברים שלא נפלה בהן מחלוקת אבל הסכימו עליהם ויש מהם מה שנפלה בו מחלוקת בין שתי דעות זה אומר בכה וזה אומר בכה זה סובר סברא ונתחזקה לדעתו וזה סובר סברא ונתחזקה לדעתו כי מדות ההיקש שעל דרך התוכחת יקרה בסברותיהם המקרה הזה וכשהיתה נופלת המחלוקת היו הולכים אחרי הרוב כמו שנאמר אחרי רבים להטות (שמות כג) ודע שהנבואה אינה מועילה בפירושי התורה ובהוצאת ענפי המצות בשלש עשרה מדות אבל מה שיעשה יהושע ופנחס בענין העיון והסברא הוא שיעשה רבינא ורב אשי אבל יתרון הנביא ופעלו במצוה אם תשאל עליו הוא חי נפשי מן העיקרים הגדולים העצומים שעליו משען הדת ויסודה:
>
> וכאשר מת יהושע בן נון ע"ה למד לזקנים מה שקבל מן הפירוש ומה שהוציאו בזמנו מן הדינים ולא נפל עליו מחלוקת. ואשר נפל בו מחלוקת פסקו בו הדין על פי רוב הזקנים. ועליהם אמר הכתוב (יהושע כד) וכל ימי הזקנים אשר האריכו ימים אחרי יהושע. ואחר כן למדו הזקנים ההם מה שקבלו מפי יהושע אל הנביאים ע"ה והנביאים למדו זה לזה. ואין זמן שלא היה בו התבוננות וחדוש הענינים. והיו חכמי כל דור משימים דברי הקודמין עיקר והיו לומדין מהם ומחדשים ענינים. והעיקרים המקובלים לא נחלקו בהם.
>
> ע"ש ומימות משה רבינו עד רבינו הקדוש ע"ה לא חיברו חיבור שמלמדין אותו ברבים בתורה שבע"פ אלא שבכל דור ודור ראש בית דין או נביא שהיה באותו הדור כותב לעצמו זכרון השמועות ששמע מרבותיו והוא מלמד על פה.

Answer (score 1):

In sefer hamitzvos, 'שרש ב, the Rambam [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Shorashim.2.2)

> כל מה שיוציא אדם ענפים מן השרשים שנאמרו לו למשה בסיני בבאור והם תרי"ג מצות **ואפילו היה המוציא משה בעצמו** אין ראוי למנותם. והראיה על זה כלו אמרם בגמרא תמורה (דף ט"ז) אלף ושבע מאות קלין וחמורין וגזירות שוות ודקדוקי סופרים שנשתכחו בימי אבלו של משה ואעפ"כ החזירן עתניאל בן קנז מפלפולו שנאמר כל איש אשר יכה את קרית ספר ולכדה וגו' וילכדה עתניאל בן קנז. וכשהיו כך הנשכחות כמה היה הכלל שנשכח ממנו זה המספר, כי גם מן השקר שנאמר שנשכח ממנו כל מה שנודע ובלא ספק היו אותם הדינים המוצאים בקל וחומר ובזולתו מהמדות אלפים רבים ואלו כלם היו נודעים בימי משה. **ונאמר עליהם דקדוקי סופרים כי כל מה שלא שמעו בסיני בבאור הנה הוא מדברי סופרים.**

If Moshe himself chose to rely on the י"ג מדות and ריבויים rather than rely on prophecy (not unlike the Vilna Gaon, who [refused](http://rechovot.blogspot.com/2012/09/the-vilna-gaon-maggid-and-work-ethic-of.html?m=1) the offers of מלאכים to teach him Torah), I'm sure others did so as well.

Or perhaps G-d was silent on some questions, preferring them to be derived rather than prophesied. Either way it seems likely that at least according to the Rambam, chiddushei Torah were alive and well even in that generation.